# php to split a neg sum from 0 into 2 variables

Tags: php, math, sum

Ran into a bit of a problem with a php page I'm building for our game tracking.... the background.. 
the in game monetary system of course stays constant but with it being my profile and others playing I've built pages to allow us to keep up on who wins what. A user can 'borrow' from another and I've got the basic page down that allows it to both track the users neg balance and keep the balance on the + side as the amount is repaid... The page works great but at the time the user is to "pay" off their balance we have to pull out ye ole calculator. I depensed with posting any code on my attempts to split a sum in half [the user has a -300 balance and pays 500 on that balance] with the math as it is now the payment applies the + balance to both lender/borrower.. and my attempts to split it seem even to me arcane :-D
Which would be the simplest method of spliting a sum from 0 to give me the neg amount and pos amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should record transaction through a double entry mechanism

```
1- One user is a lender
2- Other is the borrower

So the amount will be added to borrower's balance. And deducted from lender's balance.

Lender Original Balance: 400
Transferred: -200
Lender Ending Balance: 400-200=200

Borrower Original Balance: -100
Transferred: +200
Borrower Ending Balance: -100+200=100
```

Comment: PHP can be as follows:
$LInitialBalance = 400;
$Shared = 200;
$lenderBalance = $InitialBalance;
$LFinalBalance = $InitialBalance - $Shared;

$BInitialBalance = -100;
$Shared = 200;
$BorrowerBalance = $BInitialBalance;
$BFinalBalance = $InitialBalance + $Shared;

Comment: that seems to be what happens currently. $TLLL = file_get_contents("../files/WoT_Silver_$USNL.txt"); $TLLB = file_get_contents("../files/WoT_Silver_$USNB.txt"); $filename = "../files/WoT_Silver.txt"; $TLTL = number_format($TLLL - $TlSL + $TlSW , 2, '.', ''); $TLTB = number_format($TLLB - $TlSL + $TlSW , 2, '.', ''); –  the problem is TTLB when it reaches a point of being 0 and going into the positive.. that pos balnce will go into the lender also

Comment: $TLLB - $TlSL + $TlSW
What is TlSW? What do you mean by positive balance going into the ledger?
If ($amount < 0) { $negbalance = $amount - 0; echo $negbalance; } 

That will show how much negative the balance went

Comment: tlsw for now means total silver won.., I have a ton of digits in my head so I try and keep the building process very easy to recall. I can open up a script I made last week and sit and wonder how in the world I did it lol. The balance in game doesn't allow for tansactions beyond win/lose. the borrower is borrowing against another players part of the total balance, in both win/lose the amount has to be applied to both players up to 0 to stay on track with the game balance.

Comment: Many thanks for the help.. The 'answer' was right in the equations.. I forced it to show out puts and sure enough the Pos balance was right there all the time.. I am really surprised how much php is to simple ole windows batch files

Comment: You are welcome. I will appreciate if you kindly accept it as an answer if it was useful enough. That's what that keeps us alive and vibrant.